# Cron Job running multiple times a day everyday

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, cron

Here that I have so far:

```
    const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
         new CronJob({
                // cronTime: '0 */2 * * *',
                cronTime: '* * * * *', // every minute
                onTick: async function() {
                  console.log('test)
                },
                start: true
              });
```

How can I run it 8 times a day every day:
6AM, 9AM, 12PM, 3PM, 6PM, 9PM, 12AM, 3AM.
ALL time in est.

Edit: Actually i need to run 15 mins before those timestamp above.

Comment: I know i can have 8 cronjobs but there should be smarter way to do it, right?

Comment: You can run a hourly cronjob and check in the script what time it is before you execute the code.

Comment: I think `0 */3 * * *'`

Comment: You're missing the `}` to match `function() {`.

Comment: @Barmar removed incidentally when was copy-pasted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the pattern [here](https://cronjob.xyz/)

```
const CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
         new CronJob({
                cronTime: '0 */3 * * *', // every 3 hours
                onTick: async function() {
                  console.log('test)
                start: true
              });
```

Comment: Oh, I just realize I need run it 15 mins before those timestamps, can I do it same way?

Comment: @J.Kane, you can use the following: `cronTime: '45 */3 * * *'`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: actually according to https://crontab.guru/#45_*/3_*_*_*
it will run cron job at 00:45 but i need to run it at 23:45

Comment: I think i found solution: 
cronTime: '45 23,2,5,8,11,14,17,20 * * *',

Comment: I guess, this pattern will solve it: `45 2-23/3 * * *`